# Counting value occurrence in string variable

Tags: string, count, stata

In this example, how could I know how many 0, 1 and 2 there are in each variable?

[image: example]

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it using the check-mark.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to count the number of occurrences of each digit in each *observation*.

You can do this as follows:

```
clear

input str5 string
"22112"
"21012"
"22012"
"22022"
"21122"
"21112"
"21002"
"...0."
"...0."
"20002"
"..00."
"2..01"
"22212"
"21022"
"12212"
end

generate x0 = length(string) - length(subinstr(string, "0", "", .))
generate x1 = length(string) - length(subinstr(string, "1", "", .))
generate x2 = length(string) - length(subinstr(string, "2", "", .))
```

The idea here is to calculate the difference in the length of the string *after* you eliminate every instance of the digit of interest.

The above code snippet will produce the desired output:

```
list

     +-----------------------+
     | string   x0   x1   x2 |
     |-----------------------|
  1. |  22112    0    2    3 |
  2. |  21012    1    2    2 |
  3. |  22012    1    1    3 |
  4. |  22022    1    0    4 |
  5. |  21122    0    2    3 |
     |-----------------------|
  6. |  21112    0    3    2 |
  7. |  21002    2    1    2 |
  8. |  ...0.    1    0    0 |
  9. |  ...0.    1    0    0 |
 10. |  20002    3    0    2 |
     |-----------------------|
 11. |  ..00.    2    0    0 |
 12. |  2..01    1    1    1 |
 13. |  22212    0    1    4 |
 14. |  21022    1    1    3 |
 15. |  12212    0    2    3 |
     +-----------------------+
```